# Java эквивалент C # async/await?

Tags: java, c#, async-await, асинхронность

Обычно я пишу на C#, но иногда я разрабатываю приложения на Java. Мне интересно, есть ли какой-нибудь Java-эквивалент C# async / await? Как такое написать в Java:

```cs
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Comment: прямо ключевого слова такого нет. Но если поглядеть, во что разворачивается эта async\await конструкция, то скорее всего в java есть что то подобное. Те же Futures

Comment: Гммм... С этим вопросом вам надо идти на какой-нибудь сайт, где разрешены холивары. И там пишите что-то вроде: C# может так (приводите код), а Java так не умеет, лол. Вам тут же возмущённые джависты накидают тонны кода (ну или забанят, во избежание...)

Comment: Если я правильно понял о чём речь, то подобное есть в Kotlin - `coroutines`

Comment: В Java под андроид разработку точно есть. Вы можете написать асинхронный класс. Пример: ```public class MyClass extends AsyncTask ``` Для вызова асинхронно класса используется конструкция ```new MyClass().execute() ```